# Extract weekday, millisecond, microsecond, nanosecond from a date in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datepart

How to extract the millisecond, weekday, microsecond, nanosecond from a date in Postgres. I have tried the extract methods too, but I could not find an exact equivalent.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what equivalent are you looking for, but:

- [there is no nanosecond precision](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) in PostgreSQL: *The allowed range of p* (precision) *is from 0 to 6 for the `timestamp` and `interval` types.*
- some date parts include others: i.e. `milliseconds` contains `seconds` & `microseconds` contains `milliseconds` (and thus `seconds` too).

If you are looking for logically separate values, you'll need to do some math, e.g.:

```
select extract(dow from ts) dow,       -- day-of-week (where weeks start on sunday, which is 0)
       extract(isodow from ts) isodow, -- ISO day-of-week (where weeks start on monday, which is 1)
       floor(extract(seconds from ts))::int only_seconds,
       floor(extract(milliseconds from ts))::int - 1000 * floor(extract(seconds from ts))::int only_milliseconds,
       floor(extract(microseconds from ts))::int - 1000 * floor(extract(milliseconds from ts))::int only_microseconds,
       extract(microseconds from ts) all_microseconds
```

Or, if you are looking to how far a timestamp is within its actual week, you can use `timestamp` (and `interval`) arithmetics too:

```
select ts - date_trunc('week', ts) time_elapsed_since_monday
```

(Although it is rather hard to calculate this for weeks which start on sunday: `date_trunc` works with only ISO weeks).

http://rextester.com/SOOO48159

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html, look at the **"Table 8-9. Date/Time Types"** Date type resolution **1 day**. so you can't get none of above, but the weekday:

```
t=# select extract(Dow from now()::date);
 date_part
-----------
         1
(1 row)
```

In case you were looking for abbreviation from date, not the day of week number:

```
t=# select to_char(now()::date,'Dy');
 to_char
---------
 Mon
(1 row)
```

For more details look at [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

> **Dy**    - abbreviated capitalized day name (3 chars in English, localized lengths vary)

(formatting mine)

Comment: I know it's kind of an old answer, but could you explain existence of `Dy` in `to_char` method?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Postgres doesn't support nanoseconds. For the rest:

> ```
> select extract(dow from timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40.5');
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_part |
> | :-------- |
> | 5         |
> ```

> ```
> select extract(milliseconds from timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40.5');
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_part |
> | :-------- |
> | 40500     |
> ```

> ```
> select extract(microseconds from timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40.5');
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_part |
> | :-------- |
> | 40500000  |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3aa7c06c29d11be9043b715edaa1f33c)*